# C# dynamically add array to array

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I push an array to another array?

For example, I need to build an array like this one:

```
var array = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

This is how I would push an array to another array using `javascript` :

```
int loop = 4; // this number can be different
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
  array.push([i]);
}
```

I tried to use lists instead of array as follows:

```
List<string> finalList= new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
{
  List<string> listHolder = new List<string>();
  listHolder.Add(i);
  finalList.AddRange(listHolder);
}
```

But after execution the `finalList` will look like this:

```
finalList = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Instead of `finalList = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]`

---

Every solution is very helpful, but the accepted one helps me the most!

Comment: Use a list instead of an array

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've tried, editing the question right now

Comment: What @TimSchmelter said. Having a powerful structure like `List<>`, using arrays is nonsense when you know the number of elements is going to change

Comment: @xanatos I corrected the javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an array of arrays, make a list of arrays, and convert it to array:

```
var listOfArrays = new List<int[]>();
listOfArrays.Add(new[] {1, 2, 3});
listOfArrays.Add(new[] {4});
listOfArrays.Add(new[] {5, 6});
listOfArrays.Add(new[] {7, 8, 9, 10});
var result = listOfArrays.ToArray();
```

For your second example, the loop would look like this:

```
var res = new List<int[]>();
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 4 ; i++) {
    res.Add(new[] { i });
}
var arr = res.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

For the corrected Javascript... In this particular case you have from the beginning the final size of both the containing array (`loop`, `4` in this case) and the contained array (`1`).

```
int loop = 4; // this number can be different
int[][] array = new int[loop][];
for (var i = 0; i < loop; i++)
{
    array[i] = new int[] { i };
}
```

Note that normally you would write it:

```
int loop = 4; // this number can be different
var array = new int[loop][];
for (var i = 0; i < loop; i++)
{
    array[i] = new[] { i };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as other friends suggest to use list
the code may be like this

```
List<List<int>> intArrayList = new List<List<int>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    List<int> intArray = new List<int>();
                    intArray.Add(1);
                    intArray.Add(2);
                    intArray.Add(3);
                    intArrayList.Add(intArray);
                }
```

Comment: I think the name `arrayList` is a bit not correct because that reminds one about the `System.Collections.ArrayList` class.

Comment: Ok , one can follow the proper naming convention, I have updated the variable name as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a `List` instead. A list is similar to an array, but with resizable memory that can add more elements later.

```
List<int[]> listOfArrays = new List<int[]>();
listOfArrays.add(new int[] { 3, 2, 4, 5 });
```

That way you can keep a list of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a List of arrays, instead of `List<string> finalList= new List<string>()` you need to make it's type `int[]`:

```
int loop = 4;
List<int[]> finalList = new List<int[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++)
{
     finalList.Add(new int[] { i });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `List<T>` like this:

```
List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>> { new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, new List<int> { 4 }, new List<int> { 5, 6 }, new List<int> { 7, 8, 9, 10 } };
list.Add(new List<int> { 11, 12 });
```